# Into which folder does npm install installs

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I installed an application via npm install and I can open the application in my webbrowser via http://localhost:3000/without any problem. What folder do I have to open to see what is displayed when I open the URL http://localhost:3000/ in my webbrowser?

Comment: Go to root folder where you did `npm   install` and check for server.js or routes folder to check the routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default npm install will install packages into `node_modules` which resides in your project root where `package.json` is located.
It seems you have a script which will spin up a webserver, in most cases it will not expose the `node_modules` directory on that webserver (for good reason).

The point is that you should be including the packages you installed within the script you use for your application that is served.

edit: you can read up on how to use nodejs packages here: https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm-packages-in-your-projects